# Zero btye file written to Firebase storage

Tags: javascript, node.js, firebase, google-cloud-storage, firebase-storage

I'm uploading files from vuejs application to firebase storage. I can successfully write to firebase storage, but the file has zero bytes.

The files are sent to the backend via GraphQL mutation:

```
uploadStream: {
  type: GraphQLBoolean,
  args: {
    id: {
      type: GraphQLString
    },
    file: {
      type: GraphQLUpload
    }
  },
  // eslint-disable-next-line no-unused-vars
  resolve: async (root, { id, file }, context) => {
    const { filename, mimetype, createReadStream } = await file
    const stream = createReadStream()
    const ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
    storageService.upload(id, ext, mimetype, stream)
  }
}
```

and I write to the storage like this:

```
const upload = async (filename, ext, mimetype, stream) => {
  const metadata = {
    metadata: {
      // This line is very important. It's to create a download token.
      firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid()
    },
    contentType: mimetype
  }
  filename = `profiles/${filename}.${ext}`
  stream.pipe(
    bucket
      .file(filename, {
        gzip: true,
        metadata: metadata
      })
      .createWriteStream()
      .end()
  )
}
```

I use the firebase-admin SDK is retrieving the bucket:

```
const firebaseConfig = {
  credential: firebase.credential.cert(JSON.parse(firebase_credential)),
  databaseURL: firebase_db,
  storageBucket: firebase_storage
}

firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig)

const db = firebase.firestore()
const bucket = firebase.storage().bucket()
```

I can't figure out why the code above is writing zero bytes files to the storage.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After creating your write stream to Cloud Storage, you immediately close it.

```
bucket
  .file(filename, {
    gzip: true,
    metadata: metadata
  })
  .createWriteStream()  // <- opens write stream
  .end()                // <- immediately closes it
```

If `stream` and the storage file's stream had listeners for the `"error"` event, you'd have discovered this earlier.

Just remove the `.end()` and your code should work again:

```
const upload = async (filename, ext, mimetype, stream) => {
  const metadata = {
    metadata: {
      // This line is very important. It's to create a download token.
      firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid()
    },
    contentType: mimetype
  }
  filename = `profiles/${filename}.${ext}`
  stream.pipe(
    bucket
      .file(filename, {
        gzip: true,
        metadata: metadata
      })
      .createWriteStream()
  )
}
```

However, because you are using `async` on your `upload()` method, this implies that you want it to return a `Promise` that resolves when the upload has completed or rejects when it fails.

```
const upload = async (filename, ext, mimetype, stream) => {
  const metadata = {
    metadata: {
      // This line is very important. It's to create a download token.
      firebaseStorageDownloadTokens: uuid()
    },
    contentType: mimetype
  }
  filename = `profiles/${filename}.${ext}`

  const storageStream = bucket
    .file(filename, {
      gzip: true,
      metadata: metadata
    })
    .createWriteStream();

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    storageStream.once("finish", resolve); // resolve when written
    storageStream.once("error", reject);   // reject when either stream errors
    stream.once("error", reject);

    stream.pipe(storageStream);            // pipe the data
  });
}
```

which would mean that `resolve:` needs to be updated to:

```
resolve: async (root, { id, file }, context) => {
  const { filename, mimetype, createReadStream } = await file
  const stream = createReadStream()
  const ext = filename.substr(filename.lastIndexOf('.') + 1)
  return storageService.upload(id, ext, mimetype, stream)
}
```